# Stream Audio File from Android to PC

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming

I'm looking for a way to stream an mp3 file from my android device to my PC. I have an application on my PC waiting to receive data and I want to select an audio file from my android device and stream it to the app on my PC for the PC to play it. I already looked up the android MediaPlayer class but I don't see any methods there to get/send the audio file data over a Socket.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to do this ?